# Connection of the 10 plagues to the 10 sayings used to create the world

Tags: passover, plagues-makkos, vilna-gaon

I have read in the name of the Vilna Gaon that the 10 plagues were corresponding to the 10 sayings God used to create the world (dont know the exact source). Thus the slaying of the first born corresponded to "In the beginning..", and the plague of darkness corresponded to the creation of light. Does anyone know the connection to the other plagues?

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: Correct me if i'm worng but I think its corresponding to **Ten Commandments** and thos corresponding  to the 10 sayings God used to create the world, so the 10 plagues were corresponding to the 10 sayings God used to create the world.

Comment: @MosheD no. read in the name of VG forgot the exact place though that ten plagues correspond to 10 sayings for creation in Genesis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen [here](https://ohr.edu/6285#_edn3), the parallel is first made by the Maharal (Gevurot Hashem: 57)

[image]