# Was every commandment on the Tablets inscribed with a different finger of G-d?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parts-of-the-body, parashat-ki-tisa, allegory-mashal, tablets

In continuation to ["the-importance-of-the-tablets-being-written-with-g-ds-finger"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99561/whats-the-importance-of-the-tablets-being-written-with-g-ds-finger):

I heard in Hagada of Pesach, when the Rabbis discuss the number of the plagues they compare it to hands and fingers. Some say that the 10 (main) plagues correspond to 10 fingers in a way that every single plague correspond to a specific finger.

When G-d inscribed the 10 commandments on the Tablets, did He use all of "His" 10 fingers for the 10 commandments - one finger for one commandment or all of the commandments were written with one (same) finger?

Comment: If the 10 plagues relate each on to a different finger (a source for that would be useful) then this related question might connect the ideas https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81472/connection-of-the-10-plagues-to-the-10-sayings-used-to-create-the-world

Answer (score 3):

R. Ishmael is quoted in Pirke Rebbi Eliezer ([ch. 48](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.48.16?with=all&lang=bi)) saying (allegorically) that God used His middle finger to inscribe the commandments.

Comment: Did he mean all of them? And why the middle - is it the longest? Who ever writes with the middle finger?

Comment: @AlBerko 1. From the passage in PRE it seems so. 2. I don’t know. 3. Prob the type who can effect supernatural plagues with other “fingers”.